# using DataFrame with ask.multiprocessing not executing in parallel

Tags: dask

Why the dask dosesn't use all of the cores available?

I'm running this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
for year in range(2000, 2005):
    #i have change days 
    idx = pd.date_range(str(year), str(year + 1), freq='d', closed='left')
    #to seconds , that created file of 1.3G each
    #idx = pd.date_range(str(year), str(year + 1), freq='s', closed='left')    

    pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randn(len(idx)), 
                  'B': np.random.randint(len(idx))},
                 index=idx).to_csv('{0}.csv'.format(year), index_label='date')


import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('*.csv').set_index('date')

import dask.multiprocessing
df.count().compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
```

I expect that the last line

```
df.count().compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
```

**will run on all of my cores(4 cores)
instead i see that only one core is in use**

in fact running

```
df.count().compute()
```

will be more efficient 
am i doing something wrong? why doesn't this code runs on all the cores?
Why is the second method (compute with zero parameters) is more efficient? Doesn't dask know to do the right thing? and choose the best scheduling?

Note:
i used this  line

```
`idx = pd.date_range(str(year), str(year + 1), freq='s',` closed='left')
```

which create 5*1.5G files size

the sample i posted use

```
idx = pd.date_range(str(year), str(year + 1), freq='d', closed='left')
```

which create a very small files

Comment: Note that calling set_index is *very* expensive in parallel.  If you know that your data is sorted along that index then you might want to call `set_index('date', sorted=True)`

Comment: @MRocklin , Thanks , didn't know that. But my question wasn't about the performance of this code. but more about, why this code doesn't run in parallel , even when i set the scheduler explicitly to multiprocessing. i see that only one ore is in use

Comment: Typo correction. 
MRocklin , Thanks , didn't know that. But my question wasn't about the performance of this code. but more about, why this code doesn't run in parallel , even when i set the scheduler explicitly to multiprocessing. i see that only one core is in use

Comment: Perhaps you're bound by disk?  Running in parallel doesn't guarantee that you'll saturate all of your cores.

Comment: @MRocklin, you are probably right , but why is the poor performance in compare to the default scheduler ? can't Dask downsize nicely? Should i manually peek the right scheduling for every case ?

Comment: The choice of scheduler definitely depends on the computation.   See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html